# Select elements from two lists using a list comprehension that has two for loops

Tags: python

I have the below homework question:

Make a **list comprehension** that uses the elements of both I and R, and selects only those elements of both I and R that are non-negative, integer numbers. **Note: For this you should use two for loops.**

**Lists**

```
I = [-1, 0, 1, 2]
R = [2.7818, 0.0, -3.14159]
```

**Desired Output**

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Thanks,

Courtney

Ps. the only way I can think to answer the problem involves making the two lists into one like this:

NonNeg = [i for i in I+R if(i >= 0 and isinstance(i,int))]

Comment: You need to show what you've tried so far.  We aren't here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I genuinely can't think of a way to do it with two for loops. I have done it this way so far: NonNeg = [i for i in I+R if(i >= 0 and isinstance(i,int))]

Comment: Are you sure the input and output you've posted accurately reflect the requirements of the problem? This doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @miradulo: That would only make sense with two separate comprehensions, though.

Comment: @user2357112 hmm fair enough. Sneaking in another loop shouldn't be the point of a homework question, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you're being asked to use loops, should you use comprehensions at all?  I think you might ironically be slowed down by having a more advanced understanding of Python than of programming basics.  Try making a new list and adding to it one entry at a time.

Comment: The instructor specifically wants us to use two for loops in a list comprehension as part of the solution; thus why I am posting the question even with a working solution.

Comment: @miradulo hmm two separate comprehensions might be a good idea. I will try it, thanks!

Comment: Maybe this: `[i for it in (I, R) for i in it if isinstance(i, int) and i >= 0]`. Might again be misunderstanding the constraints.

Comment: @miradulo this worked! Thanks! Can you explain how the LC works? Thanks!

Comment: @user6866797 Put a newline before each `for` to make things easier to read. The first (outer) for loop is iterating over the tuple `(I, R)` containing both lists. The second (inner) for loop is iterating over the elements from whatever list the outer loop is currently at.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to this problem.The answer is not generalizable but meets the learning objective the professor set for us: how to use nested for loops in list comprehensions.

> Since there is only 1 value in list R that is greater than 0, the
>   result of the list comprehension's first iteration is the only result
>   returned

```
numbers = [(i,r) for i in I for r in R if(r>0)]
result: [(-1, 2.7818), (0, 2.7818), (1, 2.7818), (2, 2.7818)]
```

> For each tuple in the list i, for each element j in the tuple return
>   elements that are greater than zero and an integer

```
NonNeg = [j for i in numbers for j in i if(j >= 0 and j%1==0)]
result:[0, 1, 2]
```

> A more generalizable is solution would be what I originally posted:
>   
>   `NonNeg2 = [i for i in I+R if(i >= 0 and isinstance(i,int))]`
>   result:[0, 1, 2]